# Can I project Display #2 as a window on Monitor #1?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, virtual-desktop

I am using Windows 10 and two displays. I am using Display #1 on a 24" monitor and splitting Display #2 projected to (2) 70" HDMI monitors.

The distance from the desk and the 70" monitors makes it difficult to view the screens for detailed work. I really don't have the room for a second monitor on the desk, but would like to be able to view Display #2 in a window on the 24" monitor. Another monitor is not practical due to space limitations.

Are there any software/drivers/ that can be used to display the image from Display #2 on the 24" monitor?

Comment: You could probably go for a funky setup like recording the second display in OBS and viewing it within that but it sounds a bit odd. Why not just use mirror or not use the second monitor if it is too far away anyway? Or move the window for the application from display two to display number one?